# Changing when to if statement in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, sql-server-2014, case-when

How do I change the following code to an if statement that returns a boolean 0 or 1 value? My end results I would like to have, is one column listing the interest rate of 2, and my results column with a 0 or 1 if the condition is true.

```
(Case when new_interestratevariability = 2
and (new_interestrateindex = 1 or new_interestrateindex = 2 or new_interestrateindex = 3 or new_interestrateindex = 4 or new_interestrateindex = 6)
    and new_crms_dt = @Curr_Date
    then 0 else 1 end) as CIEDIT_VAL_96,
```

Currently, I am getting something like below:

[Results Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Hqn.png)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: You don't. An IF statement is used to control flow of processing. A case expression is used to determine what value to be returned in a single column.

Comment: My results column is showing VariableA values that are not equal to 2, would like to only show VariableA values that are equal to 2. If that makes sense

Comment: You might consider using IN instead of all those ORs in there. And VariableB in (1, 2,3,4,5,6)

Comment: If you want to filter the results you would need to use a where clause.

Comment: How would I rewrite using a where clause? Sorry still learning

Comment: Yeah, if you could show us some sample data, what results you're getting and what results you want, that would be helpful. Right now, we're guessing at what you want.

Comment: The WHERE clause goes after the tables and joins. This is the most basic of elements in writing queries. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Ok i updated my quesiton to show what I have vs. what I need

Answer (score 1):

To filter rows, use a Where clause.  The Case statement in the Select clause will modify the value shown on the row.

```
Select *
from table
Where new_interestratevariability = 2
      and new_interestrateindex IN (1,2,3,4,6)
      and new_crms_dt = @Curr_Date
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @DimaSan, Thank you, that is good advice.  My answer updated, though it appears the OP was asking a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer, it was as simple as adding "not in" instead of just "in". Thanks everyone

```
(Case when new_interestratevariability = 2
and (new_interestrateindex not in(1,2,3,4,6))
    and new_crms_dt = @Curr_Date
        then 1 else 0 end) as CIEDIT_VAL_96,
```